# Can't import python script to another (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, scripting

So I have two python scripts- main.py and gui.py in the same directory/folder. But when I try to import `main.py` in `gui.py`, it doesn't work. It's the same when I try to import `gui.py` in `main.py`

I tried it this way

```
from main import *
```

I saw several questions about similar things but nothing works. Please help and thanks in advance! I'm using Pycharm and Python 3.10

Comment: Can you share the error.

Comment: No error in this way. but if I use `from .main import *`, variables and functions can be used but it gives `attempted relative import with no known parent package` error when compiling.

Comment: "when I try to import main.py in gui.py, it doesn't work" "I saw several questions about similar things but nothing works." "No error in this way." I don't understand. Is there a problem or not? "variables and functions can be used but it gives attempted relative import with no known parent package error when compiling" You can always "use" (i.e., write the code) any variable or function name, no matter whether it was defined or not. The error is detected *when the program runs*. Python's "compilation" does very little - you can only get a `SyntaxError`. Imports happen at runtime.

Comment: "I saw several questions about similar things but nothing works." Specifically what things did you try, and what happened when you tried them? Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: "attempted relative import with no known parent package" Okay; did you try searching specifically for questions about this error? Did you try *those* solutions?

Answer (score 1):

from . import main

and then, to call a function that belongs to main.py, you should do;

main.function_name()

Comment: Ouch, it gives the same error too :(   I guess it's same as `from .main import *`. Error is
`attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Can you try to do global import? like, import directory_name.main

Comment: doesn't work either...